# Is there a difference between game sense and game theory?

Tags: game-theory

Do they mean the same when talking about interdependent decision making.

Comment: What is "game sense"? The popular technique for [teaching kids how to play sports](https://www.science.gov/topicpages/g/game+sense+approach)? If so, the difference is the same as between college algebra and interactive methods of teaching it.

Answer (score 1):

"[Game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory)" is a field of mathematics which studies rational decision-making in certain abstract interactions called "games" - which are not exactly sports games.  A game in game theory involves some number of players who each select an action.  Then as a result of the chosen actions, each player is given a reward or penalty, from values given in a payoff matrix.  The game may be repeated some number of times.  Mathematicians study optimal strategies in such games, or in variants of them.

"Game sense" is an informal term used in sports for how well a player understands what's happening or soon to happen on the field.  It's almost completely unrelated to the mathematical study of game theory.